# What happens when you set --user-data-dir to an empty string in google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

The following command actually works and opens the browser.

```
google-chrome --user-data-dir=""
```

Is chrome using a default location or is it writing to a new location or something else?

Comment: I don't know but you can easily check it yourself: Try starting Chrome like this, go to `chrome://version/` and check what `Profile Path` is in use.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about that. Looks like chrome uses the default directory in this case.